# TSQL How to find a patern inside a string?

Tags: t-sql

I have a string:

```
'This is some random text so you don't get upset [rethink]'
```

or this string

```
'This is some random text so you don't get upset [me] and [123]'
```

Is it possible using TSQL to find and replace the [text] strings?

The result:

```
'This is some random text so you don't get upset '
```

or this string

```
'This is some random text so you don't get upset  and '
```

**EDIT:**

I have modified the accepted answer so that the function to be more dynamic:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StripTagWithChar]
(@TagLeft NVARCHAR(1),@TagText NVARCHAR(MAX),@TagRight NVARCHAR(1))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX(@TagLeft,@TagText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX(@TagRight,@TagText,@Start+1)
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1

    WHILE (@Start > 0
        AND @End > 0
        AND @Length > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @TagText = STUFF(@TagText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX(@TagLeft,@TagText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX(@TagRight,@TagText,@Start+1)
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END

    RETURN Replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(@TagText)),'  ',' ')
END
```

Now this function accepts the enclosing brackets as an input:

```
select [dbo].[StripTagWithChar]( '{' , 'this is {not} awesome' , '}' )
```

And the most cool thing is that now it will filter tags with identical brackets like this:

```
select [dbo].[StripTagWithChar]( '=' , 'this is =not= awesome' , '=' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest making some slight modifications to [a previously created UDF that strips out HTML tags](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/)... simply replace the `<` and `>` with `[` and `]`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripTag]
(@TagText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('[',@TagText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX(']',@TagText,CHARINDEX('[',@TagText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1

    WHILE (@Start > 0
        AND @End > 0
        AND @Length > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @TagText = STUFF(@TagText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('[',@TagText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX(']',@TagText,CHARINDEX('[',@TagText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END

    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@TagText))
END
GO
```

Comment: I have just noticed that this function uses VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR. This is terrible, you should never use VARCHAR.